# Losing local storage data when updating the ionic-webview plugin version from 1.2.1 to 4.1.3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-webview

Currently I am using ionic-webview plugin version 1.2.1, ionic3, cordova 8.1.2, cordova-ios 4.5.5 and codova-android 7.1.2.
And I am updating my App with ionic-webview plugin version 4.1.3, ionic4, cordova 9.0.0, cordova-ios 5.0.1 and codova-android 8.x.x.

So while updating my app I am losing the data stored in local storage. Many have suggested to go with a bridge release (2 releases. First one with all old versions AND with sq lite/ionic storage to store local data and next release with all these updates).

I don't have this bridge release option because of some other reasons.
Can anyone suggest me a solution or any other plugin to solve this issue with one go (single release)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "while updating my app I am losing the data stored in local storage", by updating you mean the installation from the app store or what? also would suggest to give a try to firebase offline capabilites

Comment: @Camilo Casadiego thanks for the response, Am storing device id and user id in local storege. Updating means: Initially am running my current prod app on xcode simulator (iphone x) (built with ionic-webview 1.2.1, cordova 8.x, ionic3...). Later am building the same app (built with ionic-webview 4.1.3, cordova 9.x, ionic4...)and targeting the same device (iphone x). After this am loosing the data I have stored in local storage

Comment: just an advice, try not to work on any kind of simulators, in my experience, it has always gave me headaches and weird behaviors so bottom line, work on a real device, also keep in mind that localStorage is just a wrapper for W3C Web Storage so its possible that data still exists, but your new build just can't access it

Comment: tried with this fork https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-webview-update-causes-storage-loss/152594/7. need to test more

Comment: Nope this plugin is not working as expected, the toughest part is I cannot test the persistence of local storage unless I upload the app to test flight. I cannot trust simulator or a real device. Is there ay other way to test this??